# Synonyms for "show" (verb)?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When I am describing a chart like a bar chart, what else expressions can I use instead of "The chart shows that" to avoid using "shows" too many times? Maybe like "it reveals..." or "it indicates..."

Comment: Do you have specific reasons why "shows" doesn't work?

Comment: @NathanTuggy just want to avoid using "Shows" too many times in an article :)

Comment: Just delete it. Instead of "The chart shows that X," just say "X (see chart 2)".

Comment: Depends on the context, there are some options such as: display, exhibit etc. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> reveals
>   indicates
>   demonstrates
>   illustrates
>   exhibits
>   presents

basically any synonyms of possible.

What is important is the context which will determine which alternative words are appropriate.

Comment: 1+. I think also **display**. Isn't it? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/display

Comment: Yes, "The chart displays..." works.